# Comparing None's of Different Types

Tags: scala

Why does each `None` (of different `Option` types) evaluate to true?

```
scala> val x: Option[String] = None
x: Option[String] = None

scala> val y: Option[Int] = None
y: Option[Int] = None
```

Both `x` and `y` are `Option`'s of separate types, yet their `None`'s equal each other.

```
scala> x == y
res0: Boolean = true
```

Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without looking at the actual implementation, I would assume that `None` is actually a case object. Hence, there is *exactly one* `None` in your memory. So both are the same thing. And identity obviously implies equality.

As to the question, why you can actually compare the two: This is due to Scala's subtyping: Every `Object` has an `equals` method, and this method is what you are using with the `==` operator.

edit: I found the implementation [On github](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L320) you can see, that None is indeed a case object. There also is no equals() method, so you are using the one which is automatically generated for case classes. Hence the comment below about type erasure also applies to your `Some()` case.

Comment: I imagine this also has to do with type erasure. At runtime the JVM knows nothing about the generic (unless you do things with `ClassTag` and its ilk.

Answer (score 3):

And `1 == "string"` returns `false`. Standard equality check in Scala is not type safe, i.e:

```
final def ==(arg0: Any): Boolean
```

If you want typesafety use `===` with `Equal` Typeclass from scalaz.

Comment: Wouldn't you want `1 == 1.0` to compile?

Comment: @Jasper-M Nothing stops you from comparing ints with doubles, if you can show an evidence of types equality, but this would solve problems like in the question

Comment: @Jasper-M generally no. With a floating point: HELL NO. Anytime you are trying to check equality involving floating point numbers, you are likely to be making mistakes.

Comment: `1 == .99999999999999999D
res0: Boolean = true`

Answer (score 3):

There are really two questions here:

1. Why does `x == y` typecheck in your REPL?
2. Why do they equal each other?

`x == y` compiles because `==` in Scala is not type safe:

```
scala> "x" == 1
res4: Boolean = false
```

So why do they equal each other? An `Option` in Scala is conceptually similar to an Algebraic Data Type in Haskell:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

But if you look at the [Option.scala source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.1/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L1), you'll see that an `Option` is defined (simplifying somewhat) as:

```
sealed abstract class Option[+A] extends Product with Serializable
final case class Some[+A](x: A) extends Option[A]
case object None extends Option[Nothing]
```

On the `Some` side, you can see a case class with parameterized type `+A` - so a someish `Option[Int]` becomes `Some[Int]`.

However, on the `None` side, you see an `Option[Nothing]` object, so a noneish `Option[Int]` and a noneish `Option[String]` both become an `Option[Nothing]` object, and hence equal each other.

As @TravisBrown points out, Scalaz catches this much earlier, at compile time:

```
scala> import scalaz._
scala> import Scalaz._
scala> val x: Option[String] = None
scala> val y: Option[Int] = None
scala> x === y
<console>:16: error: could not find implicit value for parameter F0: scalaz.Equal[Object]
          x === y
scala> val z: Option[String] = None
scala> x === z
res3: Boolean = true
```

Comment: `Nothing` in Haskell has type `Maybe a` (in the absence of other context). `(Nothing :: Maybe Int) == (Nothing :: Maybe String)` doesn't (and shouldn't) compile, and the equivalent code in Scalaz won't either.

Comment: Good point @TravisBrown, have updated my answer with Scalaz ref, thanks

Answer (score 2):

`Option` is (roughly speaking) implemented like this:

```
trait Option[+A]
case class  Some[A](value: A) extends Option[A]
case object None extends Option[Nothing]
```

Because `None` is an object, (a singleton in java terms), there's only one instance of it, and because `Nothing` is at the very bottom of the type hierarchy, meaning it's a subtype of EVERY type in Scala (even null), the two `None`s are effectively the same type